# Total Sum/Level of Detail in Google Data Studio

Tags: calculated-columns, looker-studio, calculated-field, level-of-detail

In Google Data Studio I have a small table including a dimension and a metric

| Channel | User |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1.000 |
| B | 2.500 |
| C | 500 |

Is there a way to calculate the total sum across the dimension (like an LOD) which is shown as an additional column next to the user?
The solution should look like this

| Channel | User | Total Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.000 | 4.000 |
| B | 2.500 | 4.000 |
| C | 500 | 4.000 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be achieved by using a self [Data Blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420)

### 1) Data Blending

**Data Source 1**

- Dimension: `Channel`
- Metric: `Users`

**Data Source 2**

- Metric: `Users`; Rename to `Total Users`

### 2) Table

- Data Source: Blended Data Source
- Dimension: `Channel`
- Metric 1: `Users`
- Metric 2: `Total Users`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/68acecc6-b2eb-46ee-b5c2-e4c1687b57b3) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either compute your new variable **Total Users** in your data, before importing in GDS.

Otherwise do a self join (cfr other reply)

Or you can have a running total, which will have the final sum only in the last row.
[image]