# DATA STUDIO - Pivot filters on metrics

Tags: looker-studio

Is there any solution to set a filter on pivot tables on Data Studio? It says that in pivot I cannot set filter on metrics but... I don't want campaigns with no impressions to show. Does anybody already solved this issue? I assume it can be useful for most of us

Data source: Google Ads
Thank you!

Comment: If the reason you needed filters was to remove Google Ad data that had no impressions, I have solution for the latter. I haven't tested this thoroughly. It turns out though that if you add some of the fields for Google Ads to your pivot table and there's no data for those specific fields, your table's going to get flooded with rows with no data. This is specifically noticeable for calculated fields, like cost / conv. and value / conv.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a catchall solution. If anyone else is having this problem though (rows with no data), I'd recommend removing fields to see if there are specific ones causing that. Then calculate or otherwise figure out how to fill in the information you need from there (without pulling it directly from Google Ads to the pivot table)

You can also try doing a self-blend on you ad data. That seemed to get rid of the problem as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491175/total-sum-level-of-detail-in-google-data-studio

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is only possible to use a filter based on not aggregated formular (metric) in pivot tables. Adding a filter limit for a value to be displayed can be done.

A manual drop down list to deselect certain campaigns is possible.